# Listing AWS s3 files in order of last modified. trying to get EST instead of UTC time zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used this command

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket helm.bunty.io --query "Contents[?(LastModified>=2022-04- 26T12:00 && LastModified<=2022-04-29T20:38)].Key`

to filter out files according to last modified date and time. I get the output in UTC time zone. **how can I get the output in EST time zone**?

Comment: S3 object timestamps are in UTC. Neither the awscli nor the S3 API provide a way to convert to arbitrary timezones. You have to do that yourself.